# Button on the left of a frame layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

In a vertical linear layout, I have 2 textviews, then a button and then a frame layout.

I would like the button to be on the left of the frame layout. I tried putting the button in a relative layout, but how do I tell the frame layout to be on the right?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/content_container_white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:text="@string/t0"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="30dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/t1"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buybtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:text="@string/buy_button" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|right"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/videothumb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/button_play_on" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/videothumbimage"
            android:layout_width="380dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/demo_thumb_home" />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by simply telling your FrameLayout `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/@+id/buybtn"`, but your FrameLayout must be inside a RelativeLayout too.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buybtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:text="@string/buy_button" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|right"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/@+id/buybtn" >
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/videothumb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/button_play_on" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/videothumbimage"
            android:layout_width="380dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/demo_thumb_home" />
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Push `FrameLayout` into `RelativeLayout` or just put button and frame together in horizontal `LinearLayout` - what would be more simple

---

ps - kepp your code clean, use `ctrl+shift+F` (if using Eclipse) to auto-arrange it

Answer (score 0):

Put your framelayout within Relativelayout and then set property align parent right.

Answer (score 0):

The question makes no sense. From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html):

> FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display **a single item**.

Emphesis mine.

If you want your layout to contain more than one item, do not use a frame layout. Use something else.

Shachar